# Deny BACKUP CERTIFICATE

Tags: sql-server, encryption

In SQL Server, there are three database roles that have `CONTROL certificate` permissions. Those are `db_owner`, `db_DDLadmin` and `db_securityadmin`.

Also, the documentation for `decryptbycert` specifies that `CONTROL` permission is needed to use the certificate. Anyone with control permissions can backup the certificate with the private key because it is automatically decrypted by the Database Master key. I've reviewed using database triggers, denying view definition (which disabled backups of the certificate, but also made the certificate unusable to the user) and other options to try preventing certificate backups to no avail.

I do understand that this can be accomplished by creating `certificateuser` signed procedures that will allow a user to use the encryption without the control permissions on the certificate, but I need a more immediate resolution that works against the users in the above roles.

I want to know if anyone has any ideas or knows of any trace flags that can be used to reserve backing up keys and certificates to only members of `sysadmin` or anything else that could work ?

Comment: I've just come across this problem and am looking for the same solution. Did you ever find a way to block this?